# How to post new values only to the table. Postgresql

Tags: database, postgresql, insert

[image: 1]

This table has the values of profileId which is the user and eventId which is an event that the user can join. I am trying to implement a way for a user to not be able to attend the same event. I tried doing ON CONFLICT..

```
 insert into "attendees"("profileId","eventId")
 values($1,$2)
 on conflict ("profileId", "eventId") do nothing
returning *;
```

...but the syntax is probably wrong of what goes inside the parenthesis after on conflict.
Just to make things more clear, profileId=151 eventId=186 and profileId=151 eventId=187 is acceptable, but profileId=151 eventId =186 and profileId=151 and eventId=186 is not because that means the same user is attending the same event.

[image: 2]

Answer (score 1):

1. first you need to make a unique index on (profileid , eventid) keys

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UQ_attendees on attendees (profileId,eventId)
```

2. you can change your query to this :

```
 insert into attendees (profileId,eventId)
 values($1,$2)
 on conflict (profileId,eventId) do nothing;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for that answer. I created a unique index and changed my query to your recommendation, but in my terminal I'm getting an error saying syntax error at or near "uq_attendees".   I tried on conflict on "uq_attendees" do nothing,  also tried it without the second on, and tried it without the quotations around uq_attendees" and still getting the same error.

Comment: it worked! You just made my morning. Thank you so much!

Comment: @JasonGonzales you are welcome , please accept as answer if it helped

Answer (score 0):

Have you an unique index or pk over the conflicted fields? I tested it:

```
create table frank(id serial, texto varchar(50), fecha timestamp, CONSTRAINT pk_frank primary key(texto) );

insert into frank(texto, fecha) values('hola', now()), ('chau', now());
INSERT 0 2
=# select * from frank
-# ;
 id | texto |           fecha
----+-------+----------------------------
  1 | hola  | 2021-03-29 14:23:12.829833
  2 | chau  | 2021-03-29 14:23:12.829833
(2 rows)

insert into frank(texto, fecha) values('hola', now()), ('chau', now()), ('que tal', now()) on conflict do nothing ;
INSERT 0 1
=# select * from frank
;
 id |  texto  |           fecha
----+---------+----------------------------
  1 | hola    | 2021-03-29 14:23:12.829833
  2 | chau    | 2021-03-29 14:23:12.829833
  6 | que tal | 2021-03-29 14:24:04.637864
(3 rows)
```